# change error log output format: ini_set('error_append_string', 'string') and ini_set('error_prepend_string', 'string') does nothing

Tags: php, error-reporting

This is what I tell php to do:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'errors.log');
ini_set('error_append_string', 'APP');
ini_set('error_prepend_string', 'PRE');
?>
```

Hoping that I would get all errors reported in one file, with "PRE" before the message and "APP" after the message. (My goal is to make PRE and APP into /n /r or something...)

But my error reporting log looks like this:

> [14-May-2013 00:16:26] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable:
>   nonexistentvariable in /home/www/dir/index.php on line 14[14-May-2013
>   00:16:28] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: nonexistentvariable in
>   /home/www/dir/index.php on line 14

No PRE, no APP...

How do I get it in there, so that my error reporting file will have each error on a newline, rather than a loooong string of errors that's not helpful to me?

**EDIT:**
So I noticed that with ini_set('display_errors', '1'); the "APP" and "PRE" strings are *displayed on the page, in the error message.*

That means I really need to find out where I can change the format for how php logs the errors. For example this whole timestamp thing - where is that specified?

**EDIT:**
It is not possible to change the way php logs errors, you have to make your own error handler.

**ANSWER:**
To truly achieve what I was going to, I asked a different question (to be more precise).
[How to change the way PHP writes errors in the error log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547879/how-to-change-the-way-php-writes-errors-in-the-error-log-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation says nothing to that, I have tested your example. I realized that `error_append/prepend_string` only works for displayed but not logged errors

> My goal is to make PRE and APP into /n /r or something...

You should use a regex for that. Should be possible, as every log messages starts with nearly same prefix. Will prepare one....

Comment: as for your realization: Yes, I had the same results. The log message is not effected by append_string.

Comment: Are you suggesting to rewrite the error log file and add newlines after each page load or something like that?

Comment: and do what with the expression?

Comment: I have currently something unfinished like this: `'/^\[.*?\] PHP (Notice|Parse error):/m'`  .. Of course the list `Notice|Parse error` must be extended. But it looks like finding the right regex can be tricky here (but it is possible)... maybe google finds something as well

Comment: I appreciate your effort, thank you! I am just wondering if once you have the regex, are you going to iterate over the log file with it, or what will you use it for?

Comment: I had `preg_split()` in mind. But *clever* iterating might be faster in this situation as the log file is expected large

Comment: Can I ask why you need this? (maybe there are better solutions)

Comment: Well I want any php errors to be logged in a file which I can access, but no users have access to (security and such). This way I can detect issues on the site... And the reason why I would like each error in a new line is, because otherwise its a long blurb that's hard to read. would be much easier to process if each error were on a separate line.

Comment: The better solution would be if it were possible to tell PHP how to log errors. maybe also add not only a timestamp, but also an IP address for example, or session data, or something...

Comment: I agree that using a preg_split may be challenging in case the log file is large... What is "clever" iterating?

Comment: I expect that there are tools for that (don't actually having one in mind). But check this for example, maybe it enlights you :)  : http://serverfault.com/questions/53894/colorize-monitoring-of-logs

Comment: I ended up putting a new question out for this, as my original question had somewhat changed.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547879/how-to-change-the-way-php-writes-errors-in-the-error-log-file 
Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

check `phpinfo();` after ini_sets

Comment: it updated php info correctly... I assume the problem is with "display_erors" vs. "log_errors" - meaning it seems to me as if log_errors doesn't utilize the ap/pre-pend_string

Comment: Just a complete non-answer